# Sawtooth - Remove Pending Transactions

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

Often we have ran into problems with custom TransactionProcessors, when the TP crashes or is unable to connect to the sawtooth Nodes we get a QUEUE_FULL error and from there on all transaction go into PENDING state, including intkey / settings.

Is there a way to remove PENDING transactions and clean up the queue or any cli that can clean up the batches / transactions that are in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Sawtooth validator attempts at executing transactions in the order they arrive, when there is a call from the Consensus engine. The question is discussing 2 distinct features, happy to help further.

Feature 1: The solution for Transaction Processor crash. It is expected that the transaction processor execute a transaction in the queue when consensus engine asks the validator to build a block. If for some reason the Transaction Processor is unable to process the message, the result of which is still unknown to the validator. So, the validator keeps it in pending state as long as it can be scheduled for execution. Right way for de-queuing it is by executing it. Either put it in a block if it's valid or remove from the queue if it is invalid.

Solution: Check why is the Transaction Processor crashing. This is the code you own. The validator expects one of the following responses - transaction is valid, transaction is invalid, transaction couldn't be evaluated and needs retry.

Feature 2: Removing pending batches from the queue deliberately without telling Hyperledger Sawtooth about it. The pending queue is in memory, it is not saved on disk. The crazy solution thus is to restart that particular instance of validator node.
Note: This may not be possible in certain cases because of the deployment model chosen. Ensure your network and deployment is able to handle node restart scenarios before doing it. There could be bad consequences if the TP crashed on one of the node instead of all. The effect of which will make this particular validator send wrong result to reach the consensus, and depending on the consensus algorithm and the network size the handling of this error may happen differently. The clean solution however is to restart the Transaction Processor.

Hope this answer helps! Happy blockchaining..

Comment: Thanks, I am having a tough time in Sawtooth Production Ready for a year here are the issues:
1. I have 4 Nodes (Ubuntu VM's) consistently I get (https://jira.hyperledger.org/projects/STL/issues/STL-1518?filter=allopenissues) on every node randomly
2. I have to have 3 TP's registered per Node without that TX are in Pending. These TP's are for the same NameSpace written in JAVA. Don't know why.
3. Once a TP is down how do we request outstanding messages back from Validator that got into Pending State.
4.  Reading Block's with /state? crashs the restAPI and have to rest start the Validator.

Comment: The 3 TP's per node is a very confusing thing, I arrived on this number by trial and error, as 1 and 2 TP's registered on the same node for the same NameSpace (6 Characters) does not work, anything above 3 TP's work. 
```this.txProcessor = txProcessor;
  this.buildProperties = buildProperties;
  this.processor = new TransactionProcessor(txProperties.makeTCPConnectionURL());
  this.thread = new Thread(this);
  this.thread.setName(String.format("Tx-%s-%s", txProcessor.getName(), txProcessor.getVersion()));
   this.thread.start();```

Comment: You only need 1 TP per Validator to keep it running. You can go for more than 1 TP for other reasons such as parallel transaction execution, upgrading the contract, some optimization which can be achieved etc. You won't be able to read the pending transactions from the Validator's pending queue. Please add a queue before the validator and keep track of submitted transactions. You can however read the status of a transaction anytime (mandates you to remember the transactions sent earlier).

Comment: Continuing the discussion from previous comment.. The issue you are pointing to doesn't occur on the latest versions. That log indicates that the TP disconnection is not handled gracefully. I never experienced a validator blocking because of that. Could you please give more information such as which version of Sawtooth are you using? If possible paste the logs in community RocketChat channel.